# How to show and hide a nodes text with button click and mouseover/mouseout ? D3/JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this piece of code that runs at a click of a button

```
function showTextToolTip(d){
d3.selectAll(".node").append("text")
    .attr("dx", "12")
    .attr("dy", "-6")
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .text(function(d) { return d.identifier; });     
}
```

It shows the text on every node on screen. Which is great. But how do I go about clicking it again to make the text disappear ?

Also I wish to do this on 'mouseover' and 'mouseout' event. So when i go over the node the text shows, but I am sure if I know the question of the first answer I will be able to do the second part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be as simple as:

```
d3.selectAll(".node text").remove();
```

Comment: you Sir, legend :) I didn't think you could do it that way :)